# Почему я получаю странные символы с Яндекс.Переводчика?

Tags: php, кодировка, яндекс-переводчик

Получаю вот такие символы с Яндекс.переводчика:

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-en","text":["ГђВїГ‘_ГђВёГђВІГђВµГ‘_"]}
```

Как это исправить?

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=!!!&text='.$text.'&lang=en'));
```

Comment: Приложи код, пожалуйста

Comment: А лучше скажите на каком языке текст тут --> `ГђВїГ‘ГђВёГђВІГђВµГ‘`?

Comment: На русском, перевожу на англ

Comment: Скрипт у вас должен работать в UTF-8. Данные отдавать яндексу и принимать от него тоже в UTF-8 нужно.

Comment: Как это сделать? Вроде бы все и так в utf-8, но получаю кашу

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните свой php скрипт в кодировке UTF-8 или используйте [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$str = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=!!!&text='.$text.'&lang=en'));
 $str['text'] = mb_convert_encoding(str['text'], "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Обвернул, но все также получаю 
string(21) "Гђ_Г‘_ГђВёГђВІГђВµГ‘_"

Comment: файл где вызывается апи в какой кодировке находится?

Comment: UTF-8 + header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: можете залить куда-нибудь Ваш файл и ссылку прикрепить на него?

Comment: У Вас сам файл в какой кодировке. В notepad++ можете посмотреть?